# vba IF function for Combo Boxes

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to create a user form on vba Excel, and want it so that if a combo box displays a certain value, the next combo box will only show certain options. For Example, if shopping is chosen in the first one then only the options starting with "Shopping -" will display in OptSubCategory

```
Sub Reset()

    Dim iRow As Long
    
    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] 'indentify the last row
    
    With UserForm1
        .TxtItem.Value = ""
        .TxtAmount.Value = ""
        .OptIncome.Value = False
        .OptExpense.Value = False
        .CmbCategory.Clear
            .CmbCategory.AddItem "Income"
            .CmbCategory.AddItem "Dining"
            .CmbCategory.AddItem "Shopping"
            .CmbCategory.AddItem "Travel"
            .CmbCategory.AddItem "Holiday"
            .CmbCategory.AddItem "Fine"
            .CmbCategory.AddItem "Bill"
        .CmbSubCategory.Clear
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Dining - Food"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Dining - Coffee"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Dining - Alcohol"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Dining - Other"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Shopping - Food"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Shopping - Toiletries"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Shopping - Amazon"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Shopping - Other"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Travel - Taxi"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Travel - Train"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Travel - Bus"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Travel - Fuel"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Travel - Other"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Holiday - Flights"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Holiday - Hotel"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Fine - Parking"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Fine - Driving"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Fine - Accomodation"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Fine - Other"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Bills - Mortgage"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Bills - Gas and Electric"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Bills - Council Tax"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Bills - Water"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Bills - Internet"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Bills - Other"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Income - bet365 Wage"
            .CmbSubCategory.AddItem "Income - Secondment Wage"
        .OptMonzo.Value = False
        .OptNatwest.Value = False
        .OptSavings.Value = False
        
        .LstDatabase.ColumnCount = 10
        .LstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
        
        .LstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30,60,75,40,60,45,55,70,70,70"
        
            If iRow > 1 Then
            .LstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:I" & iRow
            Else
            .LstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:I2"
            End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub Submit()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    
    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] + 1
    
    With sh
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = UserForm1.TxtItem.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3) = IIf(UserForm1.OptIncome = True, UserForm1.TxtAmount.Value, "")
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = IIf(UserForm1.OptExpense = True, UserForm1.TxtAmount.Value, "")
        .Cells(iRow, 5) = UserForm1.CmbCategory.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 6) = UserForm1.CmbSubCategory.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 8) = IIf(UserForm1.OptNatwest = True, "Yes", "")
        .Cells(iRow, 9) = IIf(UserForm1.OptSavings = True, "Yes", "")
        .Cells(iRow, 10) = IIf(UserForm1.OptMonzo = True, "Yes", "")
        .Cells(iRow, 7) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")]
    End With
```

I have checked on youtube and other sites, however can not find an answer and have tried to figure it out myself with no luck

Comment: Do you know how to handle events when a combobox item is selected?

Comment: The search term you need to use in Google is `vba dependent combobox`. And if you use it, you will get lot of hits. For example [Excel UserForm With Dependent Comboboxes](https://www.contextures.com/exceluserformdependentcomboboxes.html) by Debra.

Comment: Or maybe you want to try by create an array for items in CmbSubCategory, then filter the array to populate CmbSubCategory based on the selection in CmbCategory. For example : put `dim arrItem()` at the top of the userform module. Then before the end sub of your `Sub Reset()`  ... `ReDim arrItem(1 To Me.CmbSubCategory.ListCount - 1)` ... `For i = 1 To Me.CmbSubCategory.ListCount - 1: arrItem(i) = Me.CmbSubCategory.List(i): Next i`. Then `Private Sub CmbCategory_Change()` ... `Call FilterCmbSubCategory(CmbCategory.Text)` .. `end sub`. continue....

Comment: Then `Sub FilterCmbSubCategory(Optional fltr As String)` ... `CmbSubCategory.List = Filter(arrItem, fltr, , vbTextCompare)` ... `End Sub`.  The code is coming from this link https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/filter-combobox-list-as-you-type.897306/

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but FYI you can also do this with excel cell dropdown boxes: [Like This](https://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html)